# How can I convert a pipe delimited text file to a csv with each data in individual columns using python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, export-to-csv, delimiter

Good Day

I am currently trying to create program in python 2.7 that takes an input text file that looks something like this:

[image]

and then delimits and converts the file into an Excel csv that looks like this:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import easygui


def convert():
  file = easygui.fileopenbox()
  data = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, skiprows=0)
  export = data.to_csv(r'C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Python Tools\output.csv') #index=True, header=True)
  print(convert())
```

This program yields this:

[image]

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.